# iPhone Dial Type Control Detecting current position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am currently creating a Dial type control in my iPad application which currently allows the users to rotate it and move the dot around to the desired position.

This part works perfectly fine.

https://skitch.com/aaronwardle/r76m1/dial

Around the dial I have some place mark numbers so for example the user should rotate it to position 12, 3, 6 or 9.

I'm a little stuck now to how I can tell which position they have rotated to and also what should I do if they don't fully rotate to the desired number.

https://skitch.com/aaronwardle/r76m4/dialpartway

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're doing something like tracking the position of the touch point to update the degree of rotation of the dial. So you have the angle of rotation corresponding to the position of the dot on the dial. If you also identify the angles on the circle that correspond to the label positions then you can match the current rotation to selected item when the rotation angles are the same.

For the times the user stops the dial between two options, you can make it snap to the closest one. Just check the angle at the point the finger releases, identify the closest label to that point, and animate the dial to that rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give this a go it sounds like a good way to do it.